# Does the first partial derivative wrt the dependent variable have to be continuous for the existence of a solution to a first order differential eqn?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

I have seen multiple definitions online where some sources don’t list the continuity of the first partial derivative wrt the dependent variable as a condition for the existence of a solution to first order differential equations. However, I haven’t seen a proof where this assumption isn’t required at some point.

Comment: Are you talking about [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)? what is the "dependent variable" in $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$? anyway, in the proof(s), the partial derivatives of $f$ are not required to be continuous, nor even to exist.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes, that is the theorem I am talking about. By dependent variable I mean y(t).

Comment: There is no such a strong hypothesis on $f$ in (for instance) Wikipedia's proof (link above) or in that one: [Question about the proof of the Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346439/question-about-the-proof-of-the-picard-lindel%c3%b6f-theorem).